# SAS is ignoring the AM/PM when converting a character to a datetime field using input(date,anydtdtm)

Tags: date, datetime, input, sas, character

I have a character variable, lets call it VARX, that should be turn into a datetime variable. The values look like this:

> 7/23/2017 12:00:00 AM

> 10/2/2016 12:00:00 AM

and so on and so on.

Usually I would do something like input(VARX,anydtdtm) and it would work fine. But when I try to turn VARX into a datetime variable using this method I lay out above it seems to completely ignore the AM and it turns them to values occurring at 12:00:00 pm (or 12:00:00 military time).

I do not know why this happens, and was wondering if anyone knows how to fix it.

Answer (score 0):

I think I found the solution, I needed to expand the range over which the anydtdtm function scans. So instead of (VARX,anydtdtm.) it should be (VARX,anydtdtm22.) because VARX has at most 22 characters that need to be considered when creating the datetime.